# Como asignar equitativamente valores a una lista con restricciones en python

Tags: python-3.7

necesito armar un script que me asigne por mes, 5 cocheras entre 30 empleados.
Las asignaciones deben ser equititativas y no se debe tener en cuenta sabados, domingos y feriados nacionales.
Arranque el script pero no se como agregar la parte equitativa + restricciones.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Crear DataFrame con las cocheras y los empleados**
cocheras = ["Cochera " + str(i) for i in range(1, 13)]
empleados = ["Empleado " + str(i) for i in range(1, 8)]
df_asignaciones = pd.DataFrame(index=empleados, columns=cocheras)

# Establecer la cantidad de asignaciones por empleado**
asignaciones_por_empleado = np.ceil(len(cocheras) / len(empleados))

# Asignar aleatoriamente las cocheras a los empleados**
np.random.seed(42)
for cochera in cocheras:
    empleado_asignado = False
    while not empleado_asignado:
        empleado = np.random.choice(empleados)
        asignaciones_empleado = df_asignaciones.eq(empleado).sum().sum()
        if asignaciones_empleado < asignaciones_por_empleado:
            if df_asignaciones[cochera].isin([empleado]).sum() == 0:
                df_asignaciones[cochera] = empleado
                empleado_asignado = True

                
# Imprimir DataFrame de asignaciones**
print(df_asignaciones)
```